# leaflet get direction

Tags: javascript

Hi is it possible to make/install "a get direction button" which will use the [widget - Geocode from another field] and then show the route?[image]

Comment: Does leftlet support directions at all? Not as far as I know at least.

Comment: Also what are you using for your leaflet? A module or custom code?

Comment: Letharion Not really sure, it isnt posible to do anything then? rooby IP Geolocation Views & Maps  <- this is the module I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this link helps you: http://drupalminion.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/how-to-add-driving-directions-link-to.html

I am looking for the same answer

Comment: Close but not what I am looking for. It have to be a link for google maps with the lattitude and that kind of stuff :)